# How to find my favourite questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

Each question, when asked by someone, can be voted up, down or marked as favourite.
Is there a way to see which questions have I marked as favourite?

If there isn't, it would be a good idea to have one!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your favorited questions are listed in the [favorites](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12795/thanos?tab=favorites) section of your user page.

Comment: I have never noticed...Thank you very much!!!